# AWS S3 through boto - checking disk space

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In a similar vein to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8975959/aws-s3-how-do-i-see-how-much-disk-space-is-using), I'd like a way to check how much disk space an S3 bucket is using.  But, I'd like to do it through the `boto` library in python rather than through a command-line script.

I looked through [the documentation page](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/s3.html) and didn't see anything that might get the job done.  Is there a way to do this or am I stuck shelling out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since S3 is just a key/value store you need to calculate this manually.  It doesn't have a concept of a filesystem that you can just query.  So you'll want to do something like this:

```
import boto
s3 = boto.connect_s3()
bucket = s3.lookup('mybucketname')
total_bytes = 0
for key in bucket:
       total_bytes += key.size
print total_bytes
```

Comment: Ah, that must be what the CLI is doing behind the scenes, then.  Thank you!