# Golang S3 bucket size

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

I'm trying to find the size of S3 buckets. Is there any methods in Go SDK to accomplish this? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8975959/aws-s3-how-do-i-see-how-much-disk-space-is-using) answer points to listing all objects & summarizing it using AWS cli, which looks to be too roundabout.

Comment: See [How can I get the size of an Amazon S3 bucket?](https://serverfault.com/questions/84815/how-can-i-get-the-size-of-an-amazon-s3-bucket) for more ways to get the size using command line tools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CloudWatch publishes a metric called `BucketSizeBytes` for each bucket with the size of all objects in the bucket. It is published once a day. There is also the `NumberOfObjects` metric if that is of interest. For more information, [see this documentation page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cloudwatch-monitoring.html).

The other way is to list the objects and summarize the size of each object, as you mentioned. This is the approach that you have to take if you are interested in a subset of the data (e.g. a prefix).

Another alternative may be to turn on [inventory reporting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html) and then process the reports in a suitable manner.

Comment: I wanted to get the entire bucket size, this seems to be the right way. Thanks!

Comment: what if  want to get the size of entire bucket in my go code and do something based on the size ? Is there something in the official sdk ? I could not find anthing.