# How to find updated S3 bucket size via console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bucket

The Storage Metrics for Amazon S3 Bucket is updated once in a day.

I observed that via CLI, I get the updated size of bucket as required, but via console it is only once per day.

How can I customize the metric via console where I can get the updated bucket Storage size once in every 30 minutes?

Comment: What CLI command are you running that shows the updated size?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8975959/13126651 this should help

Answer (score 1):

You **cannot** change the update frequency of the size shown in the S3 management console.

However, you could use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to make API calls to S3 to calculate the size.

From [AWS S3: how do I see how much disk space is using](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32257938/174777):

```
aws s3 ls s3://mybucket --recursive --human-readable --summarize
```

However, if the bucket has many objects (eg 100,000+), this can take considerable time to calculate.